# How to fetch all the value in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch all the posts data from the admin site to show on my frontend but for now it is only print first value instead of all the data's.
I want solution on this, here is my code below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Stack } from './common/contentstack-api/api.js';

export default class App extends Component{
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = { loading : true, result: null}
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      var Query = Stack.ContentType("posts").Query()
      .toJSON()
      .find()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({loading : false, result:result})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  
    renderList (result) {
      return (
        <main>
        <div className="media-body ">
          { 
           this.state.result.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="article-metadata">
                  <ul>
                  <li>{ value[index].title}</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                 )
            })
          } 
        </div>
        </main>
      )
    }

    render () {
      const {loading, result} = this.state
      return (this.state.loading) ? <h1>loading...</h1> : this.renderList(result[0])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure more than one value gets set to state.result? Also, result[0] should be an error when result is null. You aren't using that parameter anyway so you can remove it.

Comment: what are you getting when you do `console.log(result);`?

Comment: how about calling `renderList` with `this.renderList(result || [])`